# Как заполнить массив на языке С?

Tags: c

Изучаю язык C. Допустим есть массив array. Как заполнить массив array - "-" n количество раз?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Неясно, что значит: **Как заполнить массив array - "-" n количество раз?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это массив char, то где то так можно

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[10] = {0};
    memset(a, '-', 9);
    puts(a);
}
```

если же нет, то всегда цикл к Вашим услугам.

Comment: Если до 4/8 байт, то `memmove()`. Цикл здесь -- последнее дело. (Имеется в виду что заполнитель -- это повторяющиеся слова в <=4 или <=8 байт длиной)

Answer (score -3):

Если `n` известно на этапе компиляции, то, очевидно, вот так вот:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define symbol '-'
#define pow_0 symbol
#define pow_1 pow_0, pow_0
#define pow_2 pow_1, pow_1
#define pow_3 pow_2, pow_2
#define pow_4 pow_3, pow_3
#define pow_5 pow_4, pow_4
#define pow_6 pow_5, pow_5
#define pow_7 pow_6, pow_6

int main(void) {
    char array[] = {pow_5, pow_4, pow_0}; // 2**5 + 2**4 + 2**0 = 49
    size_t size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);

    printf("size = %zu\narray =", size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf(" %c", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Та за шо минус?